# What is the fastest way to get height/width of unstyled element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance

I came across performance issues with measuring height/width of a non-tempty unstyled element. Reading following properties seems to be very slow:

```
.offsetHeight
.clientHeight
.scrollHeight
```

I've read elsewhere that it is slow because somehow reading them causes reflow. At least, that's what I've found about `offsetHeight`, but the other two perform the same. There is some kind of quantum magic here, because logically reading a property should not cause page reflows. Anyway, is there a faster way to find width/height of an element in the easiest possible conditions, where the element doesn't have any style like `margin, padding, border` applied to it, or no other styles whatsoever?

`.style.height` just returns empty string because it only reads the values from `style=""` attribute, which is empty until explicitly defined.

Update: `window.getComputedStyle(el).height` performs just as slow.

Comment: Simply reading does not cause reflow. However, if you have changed ANYTHING in ANY OTHER ELEMENT there is potential that offsetHeight may have changed. Therefore reading after changing will cause the browser to recalculate the geometry of everything. What is slow is change, read, change, read, change, read. What is fast is change, change, change, read, read, read. This is the reason why React.js and Angular can outperform naive DOM manipulation.

Comment: Relevant answer (if not actually duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815810/avoiding-html-document-reflows/19816067#19816067

Comment: Here's a gist of things that cause reflow: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Comment: @slebetman Are you saying that there is absolutely no way to find out the element's height without causing reflow when dom changes are pending?

Comment: @Alph.Dev: Think about it. The browser developers have two choices here: either give potentially wrong width and height or recalculate geometry (reflow) and then return the guaranteed correct width and height. Since HTML is specified the way it is - where changes in child elements can force parents to change size and changes in parents can also force children to change size - it is not possible to figure out if sizes have changed or not without actually calculating everyting. Guess which choice browser devs decided to implement? (I'm not sure they have a choice depending on how DOM specs)

Comment: @slebetman It's a solid argument. Although reflowing full page is not the only possible way. By chance I was recently working on some performance optimizations for some multi-element animations and had to face similar choice. What I did was only re-calculate elements that may have changed potentially, avoiding a huge amount of unnecessary calculations. Keeping and maintaining a separate register of coordinates, allowed me to read without reflow boosting performance significantly.

Comment: Chrome probably uses something similar to outperform other browsers so much in this area. But from this discussion I guess there are no standardized faster methods that all browsers use to get element's dimensions. Thank you. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fastest way, all of them will have the penalty of at least calling the function and recalculating layout if DOM has changed. Browser optimizations vary, some vendors batch things etc. What you can do is to:

- Batch all DOM changes you want to do, do them in one go, by using `document.createDocumentFragment` etc., and then call the method of your choice
- Throttle the call using `requestAnimationFrame`, nextTick using `MessageChannel` trick or `async` functions for next microtask, like [here](https://github.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/lexicon-mono-seq/blob/master/lexiconMonoSeq.v0.19.0.js#L967-L977) or:

```js
const query = ((cache) => { 
    const _ = void(0),
          raf = window.requestAnimationFrame; //switch it to something else like `next.tick()` or `setTimeout` etc.
    return (el) => {
        if (cache.value !== _){
            return cache.value;
        }
        raf(()=> cache.value = _);
        return cache.value = el.offsetHeight; //change this to whatever method
    }
})({value: void(0)});

query(someEl);//2000 etc.
```

- Like @Kaiido suggested, you can use [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver), although remember that older browser won't support the API (you will need to use `onScroll` trick on hidden elements to simulate same behavior) and both API and polyfill has the drawback of events not firing on `CSS Transforms`.

At the end of the day, there will be situations where you will have to trigger layout change/reflow whatever you use. So >%50 of what you can do boils down to limiting how much you can call your `query` function.

(no framework can cheat here, and NO, they do not give you an advantage if you know what you are doing).

Comment: `createDocumentFragment()` vs a batch of DOM changes will only allow to have a single append MutationRecord instead of possibly multiple ones in the still single MutationObserver callback. And the route to append a document fragment may be more complex than appending "real" nodes. So all in all, that trick is generally not faster than appending all the elements in one batch (at least not in any appreciable way). The key thing is "do not dirty your layout between each getter".

Comment: Also, the reflow will generally be done after rAF callbacks (in Chrome and Firefox; Safari apparently does this in some kind of idle state, before rAF if it can). Using a ResizeObserver callback would thus be better here, since these do fire after the layout has been updated. But the boxes will need to be updated anyway, so at the end of the day, the exact same work will have to be done, be it by the normal flow of the browser's renderer, or forced by OP's JS.

Answer (score -1):

What if you use the `getBoundingClientRect()` method: This method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport. It does not trigger a reflow, so it can be faster, but it all depends on the complexity of the page and the number of elements on the page.

Comment: "It does not trigger a reflow," yes it does. "but it all depends on the complexity of the page and the number of elements on the page." Assuming it didn't need to have an updated box layout (and thus to trigger a reflow), why would it depend on the page complexity? (It does indeed depend on the page complexity, but that's because it does actually trigger a reflow, like `offsetHeight` et al.)

Answer (score -2):

[Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object containing the
> values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active
> stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may
> contain.

Comment: Interestingly, `getComputedStyle` on itself won't force a reflow, only reading the getters from the returned object will. Also, reading some properties may trigger only a "targeted reflow", e.g `.fontSize` is one of these, because the browser doesn't need to know about the elements on other branches of the CSSOM tree to find that value. But `.width` and `.height` will trigger a full reflow, because any element in the tree could affect this element.

Comment: Are you saying that `.getComputedStyle.getPropertyValue('height')` forces a reflow? That's terrible!

Comment: How do you want it to know what `80%` would mean without recalculating the boxes?

Comment: I assumed there was a state table behind the scenes that tracked all the computed styles, and could be read from. Learn something new everyday,,,