# JS alert function executed before if condition modifying the DOM even though alert is inside if . Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why in this jQuery example, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gahLa6w/) `alert` function is executed before `jquery` modifying the `.parent`'s background even though `if(p.css('background-color', 'yellow'))` is evaluated first.

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti qui esse illum, unde labore. Repellendus sunt, quidem eligendi aliquid architecto animi officia itaque ducimus impedit, enim laudantium quis, cupiditate optio.</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var p = $('.parent');
p.css('border', '3px solid blue');

if(p.css('background-color', 'yellow')){
    alert('cool')
  } else {
  alert( 'Not COOL')
  }
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gahLa6w/)

Thanks

Comment: `Why {...} alert function is executed before jquery modifying the .parent's background`. It isn't but because `window.alert` is modal, the UI has no time to be redrawn before the modal block the UI. AND setting a CSS property in an `if` condition has no real use case meaning because it will always be evaluated as truthly value

Comment: p.css('background-color', 'yellow') sets the color to yellow. Hence the alert is executed after setting the color

Comment: you could wrap you alert in a setTimeout function, do delay it

Comment: See what @JiiB meant: https://jsfiddle.net/5gahLa6w/1/  Using a timeout, you put function callback in the event queue, letting the browser to firstly repaint the UI

Comment: @VineetDesai The alert is executed after setting the color but before the color is drawn on screen

Comment: Thanks @slebetman for providing detailed explanation

Answer (score 3):

The browser does not update the graphics when you modify the DOM. It only does so when there's no more javascript to execute. This process is called reflow.

Basically this is how the browser works:

```
Event loop
    ┌──────────┐
    │          │
    │          │
    │          ▼
    │        check if there's any new ───────▶ parse data
    │        data on the network                    │
    │          │                                    │
    │          ▼                                    │
    │        check if we need to execute  ◀─────────┘
    │        any javascript ──────────────────▶ execute
    │          │                               javascript
    │          ▼                                  │
    │        check if we need to ◀────────────────┘
    │        redraw the page  ──────────────▶ redraw page
    │          │                                   │
    │          │                                   │
    └────◀─────┴─────────────────◀─────────────────┘
```

However, by definition the `alert()` function does not wait for reflow and interrupts the execution of javascript.

Therefore when you change the background color to yellow the following happens:

1. DOM is modified and the background is changed to yellow
2. Alert is called and the alert dialog is displayed
3. Other bits of javascript is executed until there's nothing else to execute
4. Reflow is triggered and the browser finally draws the yellow background to screen

Reflow behaves this way as an optimization. Constantly redrawing everything potentially slows down browsers so even if reflow isn't described by the specification the very fact that Microsoft, Mozilla, Google and Apple are constantly competing to be the best browser means the over time reflow becomes more and more a batch process.

Comment: For more info see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815810/avoiding-html-document-reflows/19816067#19816067 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616477/does-javascript-process-using-an-elastic-racetrack-algorithm/19620041#19620041

Comment: That's really a well explained answer with simple&great visual